# change date difference when application loads

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

So im using a SimpleCursor Adapter to load up my task list, and in each row there is a text view with the time left in it. What i want to do is update the list rows when the user goes to the listview activity so it will update the time left. the problem im having is simple cursor adapters fill the list with items from the database and i need to change the time left text via android by calculating it on the fly and only accessing the DB for the datedue.

I tried storing the timeleft into the DB then updating it when the list is shown but thats not working and seems pretty messy.

edit: I do know how to calculate the time difference. All i want to know is how can i fill a list with Cursor items and non-cursor items.